# How to display a description of a given category from a custom taxonomy

Tags: categories, custom-taxonomy, description

I have a taxonomy called **`tcp_product_category`**. In the admin panel I have created a few terms within this taxonomy. On the homepage I want to display the description of one of those terms with the slug **`all-products`**.

For all normal categories I use this code:

```
<?php echo category_description( get_term_by('slug', 'guide', 'category')->term_id  ); ?>
```

This doesn't appear to work with custom taxonomies.

The code:

```
<?php 
echo category_description( 
    get_term_by('slug', 'all-products', 'tcp_product_category')->term_id
); 
?>
```

All the values I inserted are correct, but the `get_term_by()` simply doesn't give any results. Any ideas how to fix it?

Thanks,

Chris Planeta

Answer (score 3):

Ok. I've found a solution. Thanks to [this great article on Smashing Magazine](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/06/08/how-to-build-a-media-site-on-wordpress-part-2/)

The code to retrieve category description from any taxonomy term would be :

```
<?php echo (get_term_by('slug', 'your-term-name', 'your-taxonomy-name')->description); ?>
```

As simple as that

Answer (score 0):

It's more readable and just generally more WordPress-y to use the built-in [`term_description()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/term_description) function!

```
<?php echo term_description( {term_id}, '{taxonomy}' ); ?>
```